# Are inventors' prior art submissions to USPTO available?

Tags: prior-art

USPTO requires inventors to submit their own list of prior art. Is this list made available anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

The list of prior art will be available to the public once the patent application is published (18 months after priority date) or when the patent application is issued.   That information is available through the PAIR system at the www.uspto.gov website.